# Writing a file using multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, postgresql, file-io, bufferedwriter

I am trying to write a single huge file in Java using multiple threads.

I have tried both `FileWriter` and `bufferedWriter` classes in Java.

The content being written is actually an entire table (Postgres) being read using `CopyManager` and written. Each line in the file is a single tuple from the table and I am writing 100s of lines at a time.

Approach to write:

The single to-be-written file is opened by multiple threads in append mode.
Each thread thereafter tries writing to the file file.

Following are the issues I face:

- Once a while, the contents of the file gets overwritten i.e: One line remains incomplete and the next line starts from there itself. My assumption here is that the buffers for writer are getting full. This forces the writer to immediately write the data onto the file. The data written may not be a complete line and before it can write the remainder, the next thread writes its content onto the file.
- While using `Filewriter`, once a while I see a single black line in the file.

Any suggestions, how to avoid this data integrity issue?

Comment: Whay are you using several threads?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can multi threads write data into a file at the same time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602466/can-multi-threads-write-data-into-a-file-at-the-same-time)

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Shared Resource == Contention

Writing to a normal file by definition is a serialized operation. You gain no performance by trying to write to it from multiple threads, I/O is a finite bounded resource at orders of magnitude less bandwidth than even the slowest or most overloaded CPU.

### Concurrent access to a shared resource can be complicated ( and slow )

If you have multiple threads that are doing expensive calculations then you have options, if you are just using multiple threads because you think you are going to speed something up, you are just going to do the opposite. Contention for I/O always slows down access to the resource, it never speeds it up because of the lock waits and other overhead.

You have to have a critical section that is protected and allows only a single writer at a time. Just look up the source code for any logging writer that supports concurrency and you will see that there is only a single thread that writes to the file.

If your application is primarily:

1. **CPU Bound:** You can use some locking mechanism/data construct to only let one thread out of many write to the file at a time, which will be useless from a concurrency standpoint as a naive solution; If these threads are CPU bound with little I/O this might work.
2. **I/O Bound:** This is the most common case, you must use a messaging passing system with a queue of some sort and have all the threads post to a queue/buffer and have a single thread pull from it and write to the file. This will be the most scalable and easiest to implement solution.

### Journaling - Async Writes

If you need to create a single super large file where order of writes are unimportant and the program is CPU bound you can use a journaling technique.

Have each `process` write to a separate file and then concat the multiple files into a single large file at the end. This is a very old school *low tech* solution that works well and has for decades.

Obviously the more storage I/O you have the better this will perform on the end concat.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to write a single huge file in Java using multiple threads.

I would recommend that you have X threads reading from the database and a single thread writing to your output file.  This is going to be much easier to implement as opposed to doing file locking and the like.

You could use a shared `BlockingQueue` (maybe `ArrayBlockingQueue`) so the database readers would `add(...)` to the queue and your writer would be in a `take()` loop on the queue.  When the readers finish, they could add some special `IM_DONE` string constant and as soon as the writing thread sees X of these constants (i.e. one for each reader), it would close the output file and exit.

So then you can use a single `BufferedWriter` without any locks and the like.  Chances are that you will be blocked by the database calls instead of the local IO.  Certainly the extra thread isn't going to slow you down at all.

> The single to-be-written file is opened by multiple threads in append mode. Each thread thereafter tries writing to the file file.

If you are adamant to have your reading threads also do the writing then you should add a `synchronized` block around the access to a single shared `BufferedWriter` -- you could synchronize on the `BufferedWriter` object itself.  Knowing when to close the writer is a bit of an issue since each thread would have to know if the other one has exited.  Each thread could increment a shared `AtomicInteger` when they run and decrement when they are done.  Then the thread that looks at the run-count and sees 0 would be the one that would close the writer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a synchronized methods, the better solution would be to have a threadpool with single thread backed by a blocking queue. The message application would be writing will be pushed to blocking queue. The log writer thread would continue to read from blocking queue (will be blocked in case queue is empty) and would continue to write it to single file.