# Alternatives to multithreaded file IO

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, file-io, data-structures

I have a bit of a theoretical question. Let's say we have a map with basic structure is as follows:

```
Map<String, Collection<String>> files
```

1. `String` is the name of the account (e.g. johndoe)
2. `Collection<String>` is a collection of Java source files found for that account

Each account has their own report generated based on the several factors including, compilation, unit tests passed/failed, static analysis, and tests passed/failed (that are not unit tests). Let's say these are written to the disk using `java.nio.file.Files`

As it stands, during each phase, Java is writing to the reports for that account. The file has the following structure:

1. Files found/missing
2. Compilation messages

   1. Compilation Errors
   2. Compilation Warnings
   3. Compilation Success
3. Static analysis messages

   1. Import check
   2. `main` method argument check
   3. Code format/whitespace check
   4. and more static analysis performed
4. Unit tests passed/failed
5. and more report information

The way I see it, the following items can run on their own threads to speed the process up:

- Static analysis messages (all)
- Unit tests passed/failed

The issue is I want to incorporate multithreading but I'm wondering how to reduce the File IO bottleneck/prevent issues when writing to reports concurrently. I looked at this SO question [Can multiple threads write data into a file at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602466/can-multi-threads-write-data-into-a-file-at-the-same-time) and I realize that my files need structure, so I can't just randomly append information into the file. I was considering the following:

1. Storing report information in a `Map<String, StringBuffer>` and then dumping all the contents into a file at the very end of the program execution
2. Storing report information inside of a SQLite database and then dumping the data at the very end of the program execution
3. Create the when we find the accounts/necessary files and serialize a StringBuffer object inside of the file (this sounds like an awful idea)
4. Store serialized StringBuffer objects inside of SQLite database

I'm not sure what the best option is (either on the list of off). As a side note, let's assume each will contain <= 1MB of data each and there are roughly 1000 accounts with one report (as a text file) per account.

Comment: `how to reduce the File IO bottleneck/prevent issues when writing to files concurrently` use a faster disk subsystem.  Multiple threads won't make your disk spin faster.  I wouldn't assume this is a bottleneck unless you have profiled your application however. It could be anywhere in your code.

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer as it was replaced more than ten years ago.

Comment: Otherwise option 1 sounds fine provide you have enough memory.

Comment: @PeterLawrey what was it replaced with? What is a more appropriate container?

Comment: The Javadoc states it was replaced with StringBuilder. If you want to use StringBuilder in a thread safe manner you should use external locking. Don't use StringBuffer for thread safety as it is error prone.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat uses StringBuffer and it's not thread safe. If the JVM developers couldn't use it correctly, I suggest you avoid it.

Comment: "As a side note, let's assume each will contain <= 1MB of data each and there are roughly 1000 files/accounts.". What is "each"? What does 1000 file**s** / account**s** mean? Did you mean 1000 files per one account? Can you explain the required result better, maybe with an example?

Comment: @user3707125 / doesn't imply a per statement. I was unclear though. One file per account.

Comment: _I want to incorporate multithreading_  Why?  What problem do you expect to solve by adding more threads to your program?

Comment: @jameslarge to decrease the amount of time it takes to run static analysis on a Java source file. There are five different types of static analysis being run in the file, each of which can be run concurrently.

Comment: @jameslarge, I'll make it more specific.

Comment: Updated with more concise information (hopefully)

Comment: Your bottleneck isn't probably where you think it is. Use a profile and verify your assumptions.

Comment: Also - how many disks do you have? If the answer is one - cuncurrent writers may do more harm then help as they can potentially slow down the overall write times.  Why not create a directory with multiple files for each operation?

Comment: Maybe you could read a source file in one thread, do the static analyses _in-memory_ using however many worker-threads, and then let a single thread write the report to disk.

Comment: @Leet-Falcon one disk but a server would probably have a RAID array, SCSI controller, or something to that degree. I personally have a SSD